# bower install I don't know why this happens，Someone else's project

Tags: javascript, bower-install

error message:  ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads [https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git"](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git%22), exit code of #1
28 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git/': OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git/': OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by some problems of SSL certificate or proxy.
Try

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

If it doesn't work, enter the following 2 commands seperately.

`git config --global --unset http.proxy`

`git config --global --unset https.proxy`

If it still doesn't work, maybe because the dependency package was too large, making the git request timeout. It can be solved by modifying the size of git http.postBuffer

`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`